# How can i access folder from web project

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight app which is hosted in a web project.In silverlight app project i have an image folder and i want to access this folder from web project.how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Silverlight app will deployed as a xap file, not as separated files, so it's not possible to access a resource from the outside.

Comment: vc 74 if the solution folder is like SolutionFolder/SilverlightApp/SilverlightApp.Web  
                                                   /Images

can i access Images folder from both silverlight and web side? if possible how?

Comment: @Hans Yes, use an absolute URL in your SL app in this case. Relative URLs are for images embedded in the XAP file.